# How to plot histogram of sum of two other histogram bars?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have two dataframes which have the same format which I have produced the histograms for below, labelled as 'df' and 'df2'. I have a third dataframe called 'df_merged' which is a combination of dataframes 'df' and 'df2' in terms of rows.

I want the third histogram bars to show the sum of 'df' and 'df2'.  I also want the 'df' and 'df2' histograms to be normalized to the combined 'df_merged' histogram, such that the 'df' and 'df2' histograms are inside the combined one. Is this feasible?

My graph now looks incorrect since starting 200 in the x-axis, 'df2' is higher than the combined which is not right because it is the sum of 'df2' and 'df'. I believe this is happening because I weighted each bin in the three histograms by the total number of values. Is this feasible?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

df = df[['Column1']]
df2 = df2[['Column1']]
df_merged = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)

df_weights = 100*np.ones_like(df.values) / float(len(df))
df2_weights = 100*np.ones_like(df2.values) / float(len(df2))
df_merged_weights = 100*np.ones_like(df_merged.values) / float(len(df_merged))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(df.values, bins=25, weights=df_weights, color='black', histtype='step', label='df')
ax.hist(df2.values, bins=200, weights=df2_weights, color='green', histtype='step', label='df2')
ax.hist(df_merged.values, bins=200,weights=df_merged_weights,color='red', histtype='step', label='Combined')

ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.set_xlim([0,1000])
p.legend(loc='upper right')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to weigh everything by the length of the concatenated array. Also, you should keep a consistent bin size and histogram range.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

np.random.seed(0)
df = DataFrame(np.random.normal(300, 100, 2000))  # Two normal distributions
df2 = DataFrame(np.random.normal(700, 100, 1500))
df_merged = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)

# weights
df_weights = np.ones_like(df.values) / len(df_merged)
df2_weights = np.ones_like(df2.values) / len(df_merged)
df_merged_weights = np.ones_like(df_merged.values) / len(df_merged)

plt_range = (df_merged.values.min(), df_merged.values.max())
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(df.values, bins=100, weights=df_weights, color='black', histtype='step', label='df', range=plt_range)
ax.hist(df2.values, bins=100, weights=df2_weights, color='green', histtype='step', label='df2', range=plt_range)
ax.hist(df_merged.values, bins=100, weights=df_merged_weights, color='red', histtype='step', label='Combined', range=plt_range)

ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.set_xlim([0, 1000])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
# plt.savefig('output.png')
```

[image: Output]

See [matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html)

> weights : (n, ) array_like or None, optional
>
> An array of weights, of the same shape as x. Each value in x only
>   contributes its associated weight towards the bin count (instead of
>   1).

Comment: I needed the weights because I wanted the sum of all bars to be equal to 1, so I weighted each bin by the total number of values. How do I incorporate this into the code?  When I weight it, the histogram still incorrect since the 'df2' still is larger than the combined as in the original post.

Comment: I see... I updated the answer. Basically, the sum of the "Combined" distribution is 1 and the other two distributions are fractions of that. Not sure if this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks very much.  This was exactly what I was looking for.